# Azure powershell function app getting no parameter defined in the script or function for the input binding 'Timer'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-analysis-services

I am creating an azure powershell function app that refreshes a data model in azure analysis services based on a timer trigger of 5 min every day. I have the following code in file called `run.ps1`:

```
# Import the SqlServer module
Import-Module SqlServer

param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# Define your service principal
$tenantId = "tenantId"
$clientId = "clientId"
$clientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($clientId, $clientSecret)

# Analysis Services details
$envUpper = $env:envUpper
$env = $envUpper.ToLower()
$analysisServicesServerPrefix = "myserverprefix"
$fullServerName = $analysisServicesServerPrefix + $env
$analysisServicesDatabase = "db"

try {
    # Authenticate with service principal
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantId

    # Refresh the data model using Invoke-ProcessASDatabase
    Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -Server $fullServerName -DatabaseName $analysisServicesDatabase -RefreshType "Full"
} catch {
    # Write the error message and throw error
    Write-Error "Error occurred during data model refresh: $_"
    throw $_
}

# Write an information log with the current time
Write-Host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"
```

I have the following code in function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "Timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Don't understand why I am getting this error since I have defined the timer in the bindings.

Based on the docs, I have done the bindings correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-powershell

below is my requiremts.psd1

```
@{
    # Use version 11.1.0 of the Az module.
    'Az' = '11.1.0'

    # Use version 22.1.1 of the SqlServer module.
    'SqlServer' = '22.1.1'

}
```

folder structure can be seen in the image below (i have both run.ps1 and function.json in a subfolder called RefreshDataModel)

[image]

full error log

```
Executing 'Functions.RefreshDataModel' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-01-24T10:05:00.0031544+00:00', Id=0a1accb8-a2f5-4949-a13c-74daa8f8b05b)
Information
2024-01-24 10:05:00.031
Result: Failure Exception: No parameter defined in the script or function for the input binding 'Timer'. Stack: at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.AzFunctionInfo..ctor(RpcFunctionMetadata metadata) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/FunctionInfo.cs:line 134 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.FunctionLoader.LoadFunction(FunctionLoadRequest request) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/FunctionLoader.cs:line 52 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.ProcessFunctionLoadRequest(StreamingMessage request) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/RequestProcessor.cs:line 245
Error
2024-01-24 10:05:00.031
Executed 'Functions.RefreshDataModel' (Failed, Id=0a1accb8-a2f5-4949-a13c-74daa8f8b05b, Duration=26ms)
Error
2024-01-24 10:05:00.039
Result: Failure Exception: No parameter defined in the script or function for the input binding 'Timer'. Stack: at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.AzFunctionInfo..ctor(RpcFunctionMetadata metadata) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/FunctionInfo.cs:line 134 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.FunctionLoader.LoadFunction(FunctionLoadRequest request) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/FunctionLoader.cs:line 52 at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.RequestProcessor.ProcessFunctionLoadRequest(StreamingMessage request) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/RequestProcessor.cs:line 245
Error
```

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine but the `param` block must be at the topmost of your script, so, `Import-Module SqlServer` should be moved below it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the [`param` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.4#param) is not at the topmost of your code (and it must be for scripts). The only statements that could go above it are [`using` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.4#using) and attributes to decorate your script or function, like [`CmdletBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.4) or [`OutputType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_outputtypeattribute?view=powershell-7.4) (both are irrelevant for an Azure Function).

```
# Import the SqlServer module
Import-Module SqlServer

param($Timer)
```

Should be:

```
param($Timer)

# Import the SqlServer module
Import-Module SqlServer
```